# resizeEvent not working after widget has called show()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
# code#1
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

def onResize(event):
    print("Nice to get here!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QPushButton('Test')
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()
    widget.resizeEvent = onResize
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The new resizeEvent is never fired in this code#1(when I resize the window manually).

```
# code#2
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

def onResize(event):
    print("Nice to get here!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QPushButton('Test')
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.resizeEvent = onResize
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The new resizeEvent is nicely fired in this code#2(when I resize the window manually). And I can see msg printed out.

Does anyone know the reason? Even I add `widget.update()` and `widget.show()` after `widget.resizeEvent = onResize` in code#1, the resizeEvent code just keeps silence...

Comment: I'm confused about what does and doesn't work, sorry. You say it's fired in code#2, but then that it's not fired in code#2... did you mean "code#1" for the last sentence? Resize event is only fired if the actual size changes, which typically happens on first `show()` but not necessarily on other `show()` calls, and is not directly tied to `update()` (update() may be called after a resize, but not the other way around). In code#1 your `onResize` isn't called when you first `show()` because it's not assigned as a handler yet.

Comment: I've edited the last sentence. It is a typing error. And it is about resizing the window manually with mouse dragging. Just realize it is not very clearly described and add that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`resizeEvent` is a "virtual protected" method, and such methods should not be "overwritten" like this.

To implement them in a *safe* fashion, you'd better use subclassing:

```
class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print("Nice to get here!")
```

---

**Virtual** methods are functions that are mostly used for subclasses.

When a subclass calls that method, it will look up in its class methods first.
If that method exists that method will be called, otherwise the MRO (as in [Method Resolution Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)) will be followed: simply speaking, "follow the steps back from the class to its inheritation(s) and stop when the method is found".

**NOTE**: in Python, almost everything is *virtual*, except things like "magic methods" ("dunder methods", the builtin methods that are enclosed within **d**ouble **under**scores like `__init__`). With bindings like PyQt things are a bit more complex, and "monkey patching" (which completely relies on the virtual nature of Python) becomes less intuitive than it was.

In your case, the inheritance follows this path:

1. [python *object*]
2. Qt.QObject
3. QtWidget.QWidget
4. QtWidget.QAbstractButton
5. QtWidget.QPushButton

So, when you create `QPushButton('Test')` (calling its `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`), the path will be reversed:

1. *`__init__()`* a QtWidget.QPushButton with the new instance as first argument and the following "test" argument parameter;
2. QPushButton calls the inherited QAbstractButton class `__init__(self, text)`, which gets the first argument after the instance as the button text;
3. QAbstractButton will call "some" of its methods or those of QWidget for size hints, font managing, etc.;
4. and so on...

In the same fashion, whenever `yourButton.resizeEvent` is called, the path will be reversed:

1. look for QtWidget.QPushButton.resizeEvent
2. look for QtWidget.QAbstractButton.resizeEvent
3. ...

---

SIP (the tool created to generate python bindings for Qt) uses caching for *virtuals*, and as soon as a virtual [inherited] function is found, *that* function will always be called in the future if another *Qt* function requires it. This means that, as soon as no python override is found and the method lookup is successful, that method will **always** be used from that moment on, unless *explicitly* called (using "`self.resizeEvent()`" within your python code).

After calling `show()`, a `QEvent.Resize` is received by [`QWidget.event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) (which is a *virtual* itself); if `event()` is not overwritten, the base class implementation is called, which will look up for the class `resizeEvent` function and call it with the event as argument.
Since, at that point, you've not overwritten it yet, PyQt will fallback to the default widget resizeEvent function, and from that point on it will *always* use that (according to the list above and QPushButton implementation, it will be the basic `QWidget.resizeEvent` call).

In your second example, `show()` is called *after* overwriting the `resizeEvent` function, allowing the `event()` function to "find" it (thus ignoring its base implementation along with those defined in the inherited classes) and will use yours until the program exits.
Also, in this case the method can be overwritten again, since SIP/Qt will not use caching anymore. This is a subtle but still very important difference to keep in mind: from this moment you can override that **instance** (note the bold characters) method as much as you want, as soon as you're certain it's not been called before!

```
def onResize1(event):
    print("Nice to get here!")

def onResize2(event):
    print("Can you see me?")

def changeResizeEvent(widget, func):
    widget.resizeEvent = func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QPushButton('Test')
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    # change the resize event function *before* it might be called
    changeResizeEvent(widget, onResize1)
    widget.show()
    # change the function again after clicking
    widget.clicked.connect(lambda: changeResizeEvent(widget, onResize2))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As a rule of thumb, everything you see in the official Qt documentation that is labeled as `virtual/protected` generally requires a subclass to correctly override it. You can see that "`[virtual protected]`" text on the right of the [`resizeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) definition, and the function is also in the [Protected Function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#protected-functions) list.

PS: with PyQt, some level of monkey patching works with classes too (meaning that you can overwrite class methods that will be automatically inherited by their subclasses), but that's not guaranteed and their behavior is often unexpected, especially due to the cross platform nature of Qt. It mainly depends on the class, its internal C++ behavior and inheritance(s), and how SIP relates to the original C++ objects.

Answer (score 2):

Phil Thompson, the creator of PyQt talked about this in a [thread](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2010-January/025498.html).

> PyQt caches lookups for Python reimplementations of methods. Monkey
>   patching will only work if you patch a method before it is looked up
>   for the first time. Your example will work for QWidget if you move the
>   call to show() after you patch it.

I think the best solution is to implement your own `QPushButton` subclass or assign it before `show` method as your code #2.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that you already gave an answer when I've already written mine, nonetheless decided to post it anyway as I thought it might have been useful no matter what. That said, kudos for the PyQt mailing list link, I'll keep that in mind: I was looking for an official reference/citation to the whole "virtual function caching" implementation (I was aware of that, but I never actively looked for it), but I wasn't able to find any documented confirmation. Thanks!